# Is this a counterexample to the converse of Euclid's lemma?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Euclid's lemma
$$\forall p[Prime(p) \rightarrow \forall (a, b) [p|ab \rightarrow p|a \lor p|b]] $$
Converse
$$\forall p[\forall (a, b) [p|ab \rightarrow p|a \lor p|b] \rightarrow Prime(p)]$$
[The proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875756/the-converse-of-euclids-lemma) here makes sense to me. I can't grasp how do concrete examples like p = 9, a = 18, b = 9 fit here?

Comment: The converse needs to hold for  each $(a, b)$

Comment: It says for **all** $a,b$. So better take $a=6$ and $b=3$ with $p=9$. Then $p\mid ab$ but neither $p\mid a$ nor $p\mid b$.

Comment: See also  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3500938/2420) for the  **co**prime generalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion here is this:  given a natural number $p$, *if* for **every** pair $(a,b)$ of natural numbers, when $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$, *then* $p$ is prime. Note the presence of the word “every”. So, indeed, if $p=b=9$ and $a=18$, you do have $p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\vee p\mid b$. And indeed $9$ is not a prime number. However, $(18,9)$ is just **one** pair of natural numbers. And $9$ is not prime because, for instance, $9\mid3\times6$, but $9\nmid3$ and $9\nmid6$.

Comment: I still don't get why it doesn't work for my example, but uses $\forall$

Comment: A single example will not do. Yes, $9\mid18\times\implies9\mid18\vee9\mid9$. No problem here. But is it true that for **every** pair $(a,b)$ of natural numbers you have $9\mid ab\implies9\mid a\vee9\mid b$? Not, as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderKozachenko because there exists at least one counterexample that shows $\exists (a,b)(p\mid ab\nRightarrow p\mid a\lor p\mid b)$.